# How to emulate mass request to website on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, networking, web

I set up a website for exchanging stuffs using Ruby on Rails.
Is there any recommend tools or handy tools to emulate 100 users , 100,000 users to access my website.
I want to measure the response time , and the CPU/Memory/Disk usage on the server !

Thanks for your information~

Comment: https://www.blitz.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMeter to do performance testing http://jmeter.apache.org/‎